# Dúvida sobre Exceptions

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um curso de PHP online, e estou numa videoaula que fala sobre manipulação de erros, nessa vídeo aula foram criados alguns erros personalizados, e após criados o código foi executado de modo que esses erros ocorressem para demonstrar a mensagem gerada. Minha dúvida é quanto a exibição dessa mensagem de erro que foi gerada, na vídeo aula sou instruído a utilizar:

```
catch(Exception $e){ $e->getMessage()}
```

Mas utilizando dessa forma, não recebo mensagem alguma, sendo que na vídeo aula aparece corretamente a mensagem de erro personalizada, assim como outros detalhes sobre o erro, como a linha que o erro ocorre, por exemplo.

A única maneira do erro personalizado que criei exibir sua mensagem é utilizando:

```
catch(Exception $e){echo $e->getMessage()}
```

dessa forma é exibida a mensagem personalizada de erro que criei, mas somente ela, não mostra outros detalhes do erro como exibido na vídeo aula.

Isto que está ocorrendo é normal? acho estranho pois meu código está exatamente igual ao do professor e está ocorrendo essa diferença na exibição dos erros.

Comment: Erro e exceptions em php são coisas diferentes, capturar a exception mais generica não é muito bom geralmente.

Comment: Sim, é normal. Primeiro, o fato da necessidade da instrução `echo` é que efetivamente o método `getMessage` retorna a mensagem de erro, não a imprime de fato. Quanto às outras mensagens, seria necessário saber quais são. Não lembro de se a configuração [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-reporting.php) afeta este tipo de saída.

Comment: o jeito que eu utilizei para pegar a mensagem, dando echo no $e->getMessage() é correto? é o melhor a se fazer? pensei que talvez por o cara do vídeo utilizar uma versao mais antiga do PHP, e eu a 7.0, essas coisas tenham mudado...

Comment: Sim, esse $e->getMessage() só vai aparecer na sua tela se vc der um echo mesmo. Mas em ambiente de produção ao invés de dar echo na tela é mais interessante salvar em log, pois essa mensagem para o usuário comum não ajuda. Eu tb colocaria um ponto e vírgula no final da instrução, depois do segundo parêntese do getMessage();

Comment: ah que bom então, obrigado por ajudar, e sobre o ponto e vírgula eu coloquei sim, mas esqueci de adicionar aqui no post

Comment: É possível atribuir mais de uma exceção a um bloco `try` assim como códigos personalizados e no(s) bloco(s) `catch` verificar o código afim de averiguar se deves ou não providenciar algum retorno.